# How do I speed up my data being loaded? ng-repeat seems really slow

Tags: angularjs

My result sets aren't that big, but I do have like 4 different ng-repeats on a given page. It seems slow. There's a very noticable stop for about 1.5 seconds before everything just renders and loads. I suspect this is because of dirty checking, but I am not really sure why.  Is there a way for me to improve this? I have only about ~5 $scope.

Comment: Without code, there's really nothing that we can do to help you. I've used nested ng-repeats on data sets with a few hundred items and I've never experienced slowness. I would strongly suggest profiling your app to determine where the slowness is. The angular chrome plugin might be able to help.

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was such a plugin! Thanks! You should put that down as an answer.

Comment: No problem. I suppose that is more of an answer than a comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, `ng-repeat` is very fast, even when nested and used with larger data sets. I would suggest using something like the [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) Chrome plugin to profile your app and determine the source of the slowness.

Comment: I used it and I noticed that I have really deep and a lot of models. Performance tab was actually pretty nice. Any ideas?

Comment: If you post some code, I'm sure myself or someone else will be able to help more. Without code, I can really only suggest profiling to find the bottleneck.